# IE11 throws AppCache Fatal error

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I am really humbled now. I have been trying to get my application cached in IE11 browser with no luck.

I will be really thankful if some one tell me whats going wrong. I did lot of reading whole day , but couldn't find what is causing the issue.

**Issue:**

My offline application gets cached correctly based on my manifest file in Chrome and Firefox.  But the app doesn't get cached in IE11 (which is the only IE that I have). I have no clue what is going wrong.

**My code:**

**manifest.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#V1.0
CACHE:
/FormsOffline/index.html

NETWORK:
*
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en" manifest="manifest.appcache"> 
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Forms</title>
        <link href="/FormsCommon/vendor/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/FormsCommon/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the index.html page, i get the following erro in the **IE11 console:**

```
Creating AppCache with manifest: 'http://127.0.0.1:7101/FormsOffline/manifest.appcache'.
AppCache Fatal Error
```

Am building my offline application using **html5, angularjs and the server is Oracle weblogic**.

Comment: Are you returning `manifest.appcache` with a content-type of `text/cache-manifest`?

Comment: It's worth noting that the page which references the appcache does not need to be explicitly listed in the manifest. Try removing `/FormsOffline/index.html` from the manifest and see if that changes anything.